# Customizing SBT packaging

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project which contains resources (template files) in a specific location (not /src/resources). I'd like those resources to be packaged along when I run `package-bin`.

I saw the package-options and package-configuration keys, but can't figure out whether I could use those in order to influence the packaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to add additional dir as resource:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= (baseDirectory) { (dir) => dir / "foo" }
```